# How do we know "$x$ belongs to $A$" has a truth value?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book "Naive Set Theory," by Paul Halmos,  'belongs to' is not defined.
So how do we know that 
the sentence "$x$ belongs to $A$" is a statement, that is , it has a truth value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The membership is atomic. Meaning, it is not defined in terms of other symbols.

What does it mean for two natural numbers to be equal? We don't really define equal. Fine, you might say they are equal if they satisfy $m\leq n$ and $n\leq m$. But then what is $\leq$? Fine, you might say that $m\leq n$ if there is some $k$ such that $m+k=n$. But you're using $=$, so you're being circular.

This means that we're sort of stuck with $=$ or $\leq$ being undefined. They just "happen to be there" and we have some axioms governing their behavior.

In set theory, the same applies to $\in$. It just happened to be there, and we have a few axioms to tell us what sort of basic behavior we can expect from this relation $\in$.

Answer (score 1):

Set theory begins with a fundamental binary relation between an object $x$ and a set $A$. If $x$ is a member (or element) of $A$, write $x \in A$. See [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).